# Iterating rows and collecting values for output. Numpy and Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Update 5/22/18: Answer by @aorr below original question.

I am trying to collect each ID and the data for that ID for thousands of inputs.

I am trying to collect each row of individual ID's, sort the dates, then plot each ID + plus data and export the chart for each ID.

*Edited*
Sample data:

- Col names: Id Date    O   G Company Date2
- aab72ffd-4d0b-4c62-b6fe-4c55b98be9a0  3/1/1999    180.66  673 A 1/1/1996
- aab72ffd-4d0b-4c62-b6fe-4c55b98be9a0  3/1/1995    173.9   651 A 1/1/1996
- a15961bc-0263-4c66-a825-1deb69bda8be  12/1/2010   55.14   542 C 1/1/2011
- a15961bc-0263-4c66-a825-1deb69bda8be  5/1/2012    49.24   577 C 1/1/2011
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  12/1/2000   48.14   290 D 3/1/2002
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  3/1/2003    69.03   282.5 D 3/1/2002
- Desired output arrays/charts, but sorted by date.
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2    7/1/2005  28.24   327
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  10/1/1998   45.11   335
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  7/1/2001    28.22   348
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  7/1/1997    44.53   350.5
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  8/1/2001    28.4    333.5
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  10/1/2005   41.72   314
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  12/1/2001   29.53   313.5
- 10a1d17b-1f5c-4a4d-8186-e4dbf62e3bf2  8/1/2002    43.24   319

The code I have typed so far successfully creates an indexed array of the the different data types. Now, I am just trying to iterate over all rows and organize the data so that it prints out/writes individual arrays/charts based on ID's.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

#import data
mydataset = pd.read_csv('input_test.csv', dtype=None)

x = mydataset.iloc[:,:].values
y = mydataset.iloc[:,:].values

#Id
b = np.array((x[:,0]), dtype=str)
#Date
c = np.array((x[:,1]), dtype=str)
# O Var
d = np.array((x[:,2]), dtype=int)
# G var
e = np.array((x[:,3]), dtype=int)
#Stack
f = np.vstack((b,c,d,e))
#Transpose array
g = f.T

#Plot data
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x[:,2], y[:,3], label ='Rate over time')
plt.xlabel('m')
plt.ylabel('r/m')
#plt.legend()
```

**Update based on @aorr answer:**
Thank's for helping us noobs.

This plots both O and G on the Y axis with Date on the X axis **for each Id**. And everything is sorted based on date. Great starting point to expand with this data. More to follow based on updates.

```
for Id in data['Id'].unique():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
    plot_data = data.query("Id==@Id").sort_values('Date')
    _ = plot_data.plot(x='Date',y='O', ax=ax)
    _ = plot_data.plot(x='Date', y='G', ax=ax)
#Plot Company name in each chart
    for Company in plot_data[Company]:
        _ = plt.title(Company)
            #Plot Date2 Event onto X-axis
            for Date2 in plot_data[Date2]:
                _ = plt.axvline(Date2)
```

Comment: You don't appear to have asked any question? Does your code do what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry. First post. I am trying to collect the unique ID's and associated data from thousands of rows, so that I have each ID's values in a separate chart. There are hundreds of ID's strung over thousands of rows, I am trying to condense it create an array for each ID plus row data.

Comment: And more importantly, there does not seem to be any problem here. What's the output of the above code? What is the desired outcome? In how far do they not match? If you can in addition also show a [mcve] of the problem, people might be more inclined to look at it.

Comment: That is still a statement and not a question. I'm not trying to be obtuse; what are you expecting us to help you with here?

Comment: I've voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking". Your edit hasn't added an actual question. Apart from a "will someone write this code for me?" question, the whole site is designed around specific questions about some kind of problem/misunderstanding/other roadblock. I'm not going to review the code because you've given no indication of what you think is wrong with it in the first place. Please consider what you're actually asking of the site and make it clear for us.

Comment: It's indeed still unclear what problem there is. Just a wild guess based on the edited post: You might want to read about pandas' `groupby` functionality.

Comment: I am simply asking how to iterate through each unique ID and output that ID as an array with multiple rows that can be plotted. I have tried iterating using np.nditer. It didn't work, it only spit out the rows of ID data. I am not asking for you to code for me. Instead of closing it, could you send me to a similar question? I have looked for 6+ hours and I haven't found code that iterates and collect values for unique outputs.

Comment: @roganjosh , would you revoke your vote now? We're making some progress. There are almost zero posts using data.query and sort_values, especially in this context.

Comment: Actually, this is going _terribly_ off track. Questions are _not_ iterative beasts where you collaboratively keep working towards some indefinite goals. A question should have a single, definite programming issue that needs overcoming.

Comment: And actually, I haven't downvoted in the first place. But really this question needs to be edited into something that's fixed in time.

Comment: I apologize, @roganjosh, I was not being sardonic in my comment. I think I'm just venting my frustration on the hours I spent searching for this, only to knock it out + more in 2 hours upon a *good* response. In order to have a good response, a good question needs to be asked, though. So, I agree with you, and I will condense my question so that others do not waste time. The goal was reached and some. Cheers.

Comment: @AlexSchwab it's fine, first questions are always tough :) But consider the situation; you're bashing your head against a wall with a problem and you decide to google for an answer. This post shows up. Reading through, do you think there's any clear intention expressed in this post? At the moment it's just a commentary of what you're working on. There isn't a single concrete question. It might seem pedantic but you really need some concrete question that's being answered. For example, search "python sort list in reverse" - 1st hit, your your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried solving this with `pandas`? I don't think you need to create `numpy` arrays for every element, `pandas` already stores them as `ndarrays` internally.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('input_test.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

for id in data['id'].unique():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
    plot_data = data.query("id==@id").sort_values('date')
    _ = plot_data.plot(x='O',y='G', ax=ax)
```

that should get you nearly all the way there. The pandas visualization docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) have a bunch of other really helpful options for exploring data quickly, but if you're picky about the look of the figure then you'll want to use straight `matplotlib` for the figure and axes layouts.

Comment: Thank you, @aorr. That is a huge help. I have gone through and formatted the lines using your reference. Could you by chance point me to documentation regarding statistics for each iteration? E.g., for each subplot if I wanted to add the mean of line 'O.'? I can do it for a single chart, but the iteration is obviously more complex.

Comment: @AlexSchwab I'm glad my answer helped you! If it answered your original question then don't forget to accept it ;) 
For the statistics you're interested in summarizing, where exactly are you stuck, and what have you tried? There are numerous answers on SO about computing the mean in `pandas` and `ax.axhline` in `matplotlib`, and the docs for those two libraries are the best and most complete in the whole wide open source biz. If you really are stuck with a unique situation that warrants a new SO question, then please ask it!

Comment: Your'e a good person, @aorr. Got the axvline for Date2 (the event). Nested 'for Date2 in plot_data['Date2']: _ =plt.axvline(Date2) ;) Thanks again. On to the statistics.